# Regex catching a weird string with {{ }} signs

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, text-extraction

Example of the string

```
{{ai|Perseverance|Garen}} is no longer removed by combat dehancing effects such as {{ai|Blood Scent|Warwick}}.
```

I want to catch `{{ai|Perseverance|Garen}}` from this `{{ai| |Garen}}` and keep the middle part same with `{{ai| |Warwick}}`

This is what I came up with:

```
(\{\{ai\|)\w+(\|\w+\}\})
```

it is quite close it caputers the first one, but with Perserverance I could do regex twice to get rid of first `{{ai| and then |Garen}}` using  `(\{\{ai\|)` first and then  `(\|\w+\}\})`.

Is there a way to do it in one regex?

UPDATE: I'm using PHP just to be clear

Comment: What language/platform are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to remove `{{some|` and `|thing}}` parts and keep what is in the middle.

You can use

```
{{[^|]*\|([^|]*)\|[^|]*}}
```

and `$1` as the replacement pattern.

The regex means:

- `{{` - two literal `{` symbols
- `[^|]*\|` - zero or more characters other than `|` (with `[^|]*`) followed by a literal `|`
- `([^|]*)` - Group 1 that matches zero or more characters other than `|`
- `\|` - a literal `|`
- `[^|]*` - again zero or more characters other than `|`
- `}}` - closing `}}`

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gK6jW9/1)

Note that will work when there are 3 `|`-separated parts inside `{{`/`}}`.

In PHP, you can use the [following code](http://ideone.com/ZWqH5w):

```
$re = '~{{[^|]*\|([^|]*)\|[^|]*}}~'; 
$str = "{{ai|Perseverance|Garen}} is no longer removed by combat dehancing effects such as {{ai|Blood Scent|Warwick}}"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, '\1', $str);
echo $result;
// => Perseverance is no longer removed by combat dehancing effects such as Blood Scent
```

Comment: this is pretty much perfect this is the output I would expect : 'Perseverance is no longer removed by combat dehancing effects such as Blood Scent' how can I get the same result with PHP

Comment: You can use it with `preg_replace`: `preg_replace('~{{[^|]*\|([^|]*)\|[^|]*}}~', '\1', $str)`

Answer (score 1):

Your match is in group 1 of the following regex

```
\{\{[^|]*\|([^|]*)
```

Comment: I might be doing something wrong but I've tried your regex with http://regexr.com/ and all I got was   {{ai|Blood Scent

Comment: That's because the desired text is matched in *group* 1. You know the concept op capture groups? If you hover over the match at regexr you will see the group 1 capture